# Get the document from solr using specific attribute value

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am new to `solr`. I am using solr which has data.Now I want to get the data of a particular document by searching into the solr. I have an attribute value with which I want to search in the solr. I am doing this by `java`. I have tried all the solution from web but not working.

```
public void searchQuery(String valuetobesearched) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        server = new SolarConnectionClass().getSolrInstance("URL of my solr");
        SolrQuery sQueryParams = new SolrQuery();
        //String queryString = "*:*";
        sQueryParams.setQuery("name:"+URLEncoder.encode(valuetobesearched));

        //sQueryParams.addFilterQuery("name:"+URLEncoder.encode(valuetobesearched));
        /*sQueryParams.setStart(0);
        sQueryParams.setRows(5000);*/
        //sQueryParams.set("defType", "edismax");
        //sQueryParams.set
        QueryResponse response = null;
        try {
            System.out.println(sQueryParams);
            response = server.query(sQueryParams);
        } catch (SolrServerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();
        System.out.println(results.size());

        /*if(results.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
                SolrDocument sortedDocument = results.get(0);
                System.out.println(sortedDocument.getFieldValue("PQR"));
            }
        }
*/

    }
```

How can do this ?

Comment: If the search doesn't work under the Solr admin page, i.e. `name:foo` doesn't give you the results you want, submitting the same query through Java won't do anything good. Does the search work properly if you search using the query interface under Solr Admin?

Comment: Yes, when I searched using the query generated by java code in the solr admin then It is not giving the proper result.How to do this ?

Comment: Which version of Solr and SolrJ are you using?

Comment: 6.3.0 is the version.

Comment: What means *it is not giving the proper results*? An exception is thrown or you have zero results or what?

Comment: It's first time I see `SolarConnectionClass` why don't you use for example `HttpSolrClient` ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have encode parameters when using `SolrQuery` class.

Just set the query in this way the client will transparently do the "dirty" job:

```
sQueryParams.setQuery("name:" + valuetobesearched);
```

Again, you can see the total number of results found using:

```
response.getResults().getNumFound()
```

The size of `response.getResults()` depends from the `setRows` parameter (that in your post is commented).

In order to understand how Solr query works, I suggest to make your tests using your browser and then transpose that requests to SolrJ.

For example the url that comes out from of your post is:

`http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=name:hello`

Comment: I have tried this, but the query which gets from the java . I have used that query in solr admin then there also it is not giving me the proper result. I want to get the documents with the name hello only. There it is giving me lots of other documents including name hello.

Comment: Could please you show us the search query that works into the admin page?